# In Kotlin, if I declare a Class in a fun method, then what is the ClassLoader of this Class?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, if I declare a Class in a fun method, then what is the ClassLoader of this Class?
The Class is only used in the method, and when the mehod is finish,can the ClassLoader be GC?

Comment: Could you please add an example of such a `fun`?

Answer (score 0):

The JVM has no idea whether a class is declared inside a `fun` or not. Whatever class has called the function, its classloader will load all classes it uses which aren't loaded yet.

> The Class is only used in the method, and when the mehod is finish,can the ClassLoader be GC?

According to https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype6.html,

> > There are two ways a `Class` instance of a dynamically loaded type can be reachable through the normal process of garbage collection. First and most obviously, a `Class` instance will be reachable if the application holds an explicit reference to it. Second, a `Class` instance will be reachable if there is a reachable object on the heap whose type data in the method area refers to the `Class` instance.

So, if your method doesn't return anything that contains an instance of this class, or store such an instance somewhere reachable from calling code, the class (not the classloader) could potentially be unloaded.